# Oracle random number as default column value

Tags: oracle, random, virtual-columns

I'm trying to create a table in OracleDB and assign random number to one of the columns as a default. I have this setup working in postgresql

```
create table table_name (
    column integer NOT NULL DEFAULT (random())
)
```

how can I do something similar in oracle (preferably without triggers)?

I've tried this

```
create table table_name (
    column integer generated always as (dbms_random.random) virtual
)
```

but oracle doesn't like it since the function is non deterministic.

Answer (score 4):

Trigger is the only way to do it.

Virtual column is different from what you want, and that will not accept `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM`, because that is not deterministic:

[Column Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions005.htm#SQLRF20043)

> ...it can contain only the following forms of expression:
>
> - Columns of the subject table — the table being created, altered, or indexed
> - Constants (strings or numbers)
> - Deterministic functions — either SQL built-in functions or user-defined functions

The syntax of default values for columns is similar to your original statement, but that does not accept `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM` because PL/SQL is not allowed there:

[Restrictions on Default Column Values](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54458)

> Default column values are subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to PL/SQL functions or to other columns, the pseudocolumns LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or
>     date constants that are not fully specified.
> - The expression can be of any form except a scalar subquery expression.